# Docker container for portainer not exposing 9000 to host

Tags: docker, portainer

I am trying to create the container by running docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 --name portainer --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer-ce:2.9.3

The container created but I am not able to access the portainer ui page using the localhost:9000[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0z5T.jpg)

Comment: The screenshot shows that container is restarting, probably, it constantly crashes because of some kind of error, please check logs of container: `docker logs portainer`.

Comment: The logs of container is needed to analyse the problem. Get the container-id with ```docker ps -a``` and try ```docker logs <container-id>``` to get the logs of container and paste it to the question description. Otherwise you may try ssl port 9443:9443, e.g. ```docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9443:9443 --name portainer --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer-ce:2.9.3```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the container is restarting. When every thing is fine the status will be running instead of restarting. It's possible that port is busy so it cant be exposed so you should check your port first and if the port was available you should check your image then to check if your image is working properly. It's better to use a docker file to make sure that your configuration is correct.

Comment: Hi Tyr
The port 9000 is not used by any other container

Comment: I have added the list of ports under use

Comment: @PanyamJagadeesh Please edit your question and add your terminal output there. Its better to send a picture of your terminal.

Comment: @PanyamJagadeesh so the problem should be in your configuration. can you send your container log ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).